# Picasso memory crash

Tags: android, memory

I use picasso in my app for image managing.
The images are retrieved from the server. A few images are rather big in 1.5- 2 MB
The image gets downloaded & that part seems fine.
After some times my app crash with out of memory.
But those images are retrieved from res (around 200kb) of 3 images only.
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=49187KB, Allocated=47999KB)
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:486)
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2044)
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:675)
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): at com.onmobile.rbt.signal.ui.activities.interfaces.ImageClass.bringInfromRight(ImageClass.java:144)
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): at com.onmobile.rbt.signal.ui.activities.interfaces.ImageClass.access$3(ImageClass.java:133)
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): at com.onmobile.rbt.signal.ui.activities.interfaces.ImageClass$2.run(ImageClass.java:74)
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-12 12:50:17.260: E/AndroidRuntime(32715): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use images with small size. take a look this site, https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html. used memory is not directly bounded file size. it is about image dimensional. when OS (almost all OS) draws an image, first it gets this image as bitmap and put it in heap. bitmap usually allocates 4 bytes (ARGB) for every pixel. and, bitmap has width*height pixels. so that, for instance if you have 5000x5000 with only use 2 color, it can be size of 10k as filesize. the file size is too low, because, known image formats, like jpeg,png, uses compression algorithm. and 2 color means, this image can be compressed very well. although, file size is too low, it can keep 5000 * 5000 * 4 (ARGB) = 100.000.000 bytes, 100MB in heap. and if you load several image like this, you can easily start to use 1GB memory (if you can) as heap

Comment: but if i am using picasso, it would help me solve these memory issue right?

Comment: I suggest check also their dimensional. if their dimensions is much bigger than the image view's size that you use them with it, you should load this images as small size. there is a way how you load an image with smaller dimensional in that link

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html#_)
Maybe that would solve the issue?
It is almost the same concept as Picasso.
But also read this [article](https://code.facebook.com/posts/366199913563917/introducing-fresco-a-new-image-library-for-android/).
Or what Google recommends is to use [Glide](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) which is recommended by Google: